Prove that any 2x2 nilpotent matrix N is similar to zero matrix or 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
The question is to prove that any nilpotent matrix $N \in Mat_{2\times2}(\mathbb{C})$ is similar to
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I've known that $N^2=0$, and the eigenvalues of $N$ are $0$. But I'm still confused about how I can reach the conclusion of similarity. Thanks for any help!

If you are familiar with Jordan blocks: then the Jordan block of $2\times 2$ nilpotent matrix is either Zero matrix (if it has got two distinct Jordan blocks) or $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ if it has got only one Jordan block.

part one: given the matrix  $M$  of a linear transformation in the standard basis, then a change of basis matrix $B$  whose columns are the new basis, the  new matrix is $B^{-1}  M B$  so is similar to the original. And, to repeat, the new matrix shows the transformation in the new basis.
Part two: you have a  nilpotent operator, call it $\nu, $ matrix $M$ in standard basis. For $M \neq 0: \;$   there is some column vector $v_2$  such that $Mv_2 \neq 0.$  Define $v_1 = M v_2.$  Note $Mv_1 = 0$   The columns of the matrix $B$  are going to be $v_1, v_2.$ The new matrix is $N = B^{-1} MB.$  Meanwhile, the transformation is completely specified by $ \nu v_1 = 0,  \nu v_2 = v_1.$   So, $N$ is the matrix for $\nu$  in the $v_1, v_2$ basis, what is $N \;  ??   \;$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
This is the procedure I wish students would learn, especially for homework exercises where all matrix entries and all eigenvalues are integers, so the whole thing is suitable for calculations by hand. That is, given square $M$, don't just produce $J,$  its Jordan form, but find the matrix $P$  with $P^{-1}MP = J.$  It is necessary to know that $P$  to find $M^n$   or $e^{Mt}$
